# Preliminary design of Propellant ducts

Tags: rockets, propulsion

I'm trying to roughly estimate dimensions and masses of propellant and pressurant ducts for conventional upper- & transfer stages.

My basic approach follows Barlow's formula for cylindrical vessels (hoopstress), but that results in wall thicknesses that seem very small.

Example: A stainless steel pipe with a diameter of 30mm and a pressure of 12bar(~175psi) would only have a 0.1mm wall.

My usual sources for the preliminary design of propulsion systems (Huzel/Huang, Sutton/Biblarz, Humble/Henry/Larson) unfortunately don't cover that topic.

Therefore I'm asking if you could recommend some links, papers or books with reliable, "rocket-related" information or best practices for dimensioning pressurant and propellant ducts.

Comment: What kind of safety factor are you using? Pressure vessels should have a very high SF.

Comment: I use a design pressure of 2x Maximum Expected Operating Pressure.

That seems to be the usual safety factor for pressure vessels during preliminary design and gives reasonable results for pressure tanks.

Comment: For pressure vessels you want something much higher, in the 5-10 SF range. The main reason is that failure modes are linked to things like cracks that will occur well before typical plastic failure.

Comment: No!? 

I don't know anything about ducts (is that even the correct english term?), but at least for pressure tanks that would be a more than unusal safety factor. All topic related sources that I read so far, agree on a safety factor of 2x. Even commercial sellers like Airbus Defence & Space design with a burst pressure of 2x MEOP

Comment: Well you should trust those sources more than me, there may be a trade-off in terms of aerospace SF numbers vs. typical pressure vessel SF numbers. But understand that the reason you get 0.1 mm with SF=2 is also the reason why you normally use a higher SF -- 0.1 mm will carry the stress of the pressure but a small collision could cause a hole which would lead to catastrophic failure. Hence why you use a higher SF!

Comment: Sure, the Barlow formula only considers the inner pressure of a vessel. There are many different loads on ducts, some like pE water hammer add a considerable amount of stress. But preliminary design has to start somewhat simplified. 

Well known books on the topic of preliminary design of propulsion systems discuss tanks with great detail, but no one is talking about ducts :(

Comment: Ducts may be treated differently from pressure vessels but many of the same failure modes will exist so I would treat it the same as a vessel. This is all coming from my classroom education, I would try and find examples of rocket motor designs.